# How to capture mean of hyphen seperated numbers in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` of the ages of drug users. My problem: some of the ages are seperated by a hyphen, for example `'50-64'`. I want to grab the mean of the hyphen seperated numbers and replace the cell with it.

1.Is there a way to do it with some sort of loop or method? I don't want to simply hardcode `drugs.loc[10,'age'] = np.mean(55+64)`

2.For future reference, is there a more elegant way of handling data with hyphen seperated numbers?

```
input:
drugs.age
output:
0        12
1        13
2        14
3        15
4        16
5        17
6        18
7        19
8        20
9        21
10    22-23
11    24-25
12    26-29
13    30-34
14    35-49
15    50-64
16      65+

input:
drugs.age.dtype
output:
dtype('O')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

- [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) `+` to empty `string`
- [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values to `DataFrame`
- cast to `float` all values by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)
- get mean per rows by [`DataFrame.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

---

```
drugs['age'] = drugs['age'].str.replace('+','')
                           .str.split('-', expand=True)
                           .astype(float)
                           .mean(axis=1)
print (drugs)
     age
0   12.0
1   13.0
2   14.0
3   15.0
4   16.0
5   17.0
6   18.0
7   19.0
8   20.0
9   21.0
10  22.5
11  24.5
12  27.5
13  32.0
14  42.0
15  57.0
16  65.0
```

If some values are numeric and some strings is necessary first convert all to strings:

```
drugs['age'] = drugs['age'].astype(str)
                           .str.replace('+','')
                           .str.split('-', expand=True)
                           .astype(float)
                           .mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. Learnt about expand=True and .astype(float)

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Comment: this is a really neat answer. Thanks @jezrael  . One question, can you please explain how str.split work for series when expand set to 'False'. I was looking at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html but I didn't quite get it. Thanks so much

Comment: I think you get lists column created by split by separator, not dataframe. The best is test it. And thsnk you.

Comment: This gives me an error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: `   using  `df['Deaths'].str.replace(' ','').str.replace('million', '').str.split('–', expand=True).astype(float).mean(axis=1)` initial value is `5–15 million`

Comment: This gives `TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series`. I tried removing the `expand=True` but that gave another error.

Comment: @stallingOne - oops, need `drugs['age'] = drugs['age'].astype(str) .str.replace('+','') .str.split('-', expand=True).apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errros='coerce')).mean(axis=1)`